# Location of keyboard shortcuts in registry

Tags: windows, location, registry, keyboard-shortcuts

Where are the **keyboard shortcuts** saved in the **registry**? (for example ctrl + alt + del)

*note: I was expecting to find this easily but couldn't find it trough google nor trough the registry itself*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa460734%28WinEmbedded.5%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Other option is: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5937-windows-key-shortcuts-enable-disable.html

Download and check what registry changes are being made.

Also: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-i-change-the-windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts/0110d32d-66c0-4ce7-8682-eeb896e80c3f looks like it can be centrally controlled via HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft \Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies

Comment: I had a look at that one before, but I believe this doesn't allow you to create a new shortcut, but only gives you the option to enable or disable the windows shortcuts. I want a .bat file to be opened by a key shortcut. I know its possible by creating a shortcut to the .bat file on the desktop and then assign a keyboard shortcut to the shortcut, but that way doesnt feel right.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/810009/set-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-windows-cmd-command does this one help?

Comment: I already got a different solution. I had a look for AutoHotKey and this works great. What you said Tim isn't really what I was looking for, but it might be usefull for others. I'll take it as the awnser. Thanks for helping