# Windows 10 keyboard shortcut for inserting current UNIX timestamp at cursor

Tags: windows, powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I would love to be able to use a custom keyboard shortcut for inserting current unix timestamp (in seconds) at cursor. While it's quite easy to accomplish for browsers using custom JS plugins, it's still not the clean solution I'm looking for and obviously wouldn't work outside of the browser.

I imagine it would basically require me to create a shortcut that runs a custom script (returning the current unix timestamp value) and inserts this scripts' output at the cursor. But while writing the script seems trival, I don't even know where to start with all the remaining of this task.

Comment: Apparently, registering a keyboard shortcut in Windows isn't particularly easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398476/location-of-keyboard-shortcuts-in-registry

Comment: I suggest looking into something like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Yes, AutoHotKey does that. But I'm looking for a way to actually achieve this without any third-party software being installed. I figured out it's easy to trigger a shortcut (e.g. pointing to a PS script) by setting up a shortcut in the shortcut file properties, but still trying to figure out how to insert current unix at cursor. If I succeed I guess I'll for the first time post an answer to my own question.

Comment: What's wrong with using third-party software?

Comment: What does `at cursor` mean here? In a certain application or editor, or anywhere you may have some text field providing you a typing cursor? In Word for instance you can run a macro. Various editors provide some means of creating your own codeblocks and hooking them up inside the menu with a self-defined hotkey. This question is way too broad..

Answer (score 0):

This approach requires you to execute a shortcut key combination and *then* `Ctrl + V`. It isn't exactly what you're looking for, but should be pretty close. It uses `Set-Clipboard` to place the Unix timestamp on the clipboard so it can be pasted to a desired location.

1. Open **File Explorer** and navigate to a location where you'll create
   the shortcut
2. **Right-click** > **New** > **Shortcut**
3. In the **Type the location of the item** field, input (all on one line):
   `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "&{Set-Clipboard -Value ([string](Get-Date -UFormat %s -Millisecond 0))}" -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`
4. Input a **Name** for the shortcut and click **Finish**
5. **Right-click** the newly created shortcut and select **Properties**
6. Change **Run** to **Minimized**
7. Click inside the **Shortcut key** field and execute your desired shortcut key combination to capture it; e.g., `Ctrl + Alt + [`
8. Click **OK**
9. To run the shortcut, execute the earlier-captured shortcut key combination (which places the Unix timestamp on the clipboard), and then `Ctrl + V`.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell 5.1+ has the native module called PSReadline. This module has the `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler`, `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler` and `Remove-PSReadlineKeyHandler`.

Using these cmdlets you could create your own KeyHandler for this custom unixdate output. Below I bound the key combination `Ctrl+Alt+u` to this, but it could be any key combination.

*note: the ` below are in case you want to paste the example directly into PowerShell*

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+Alt+u `
-ScriptBlock { 
$unixDate = $([uint64](New-TimeSpan -Start "01/01/1970" -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds)
[Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert("$unixDate")
} -BriefDescription "Unix TimeStamp" `
-Description "Returns the current Unix TimeStamp"
```

If you also want it to copy to your clipboard for pasting in another program then you may add `[Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Copy()` after the insert.

The KeyHandler is only active during your current session, so If you want to make this a semi permanent key combo for every new PowerShell Session you should add this to your PowerShell profile. Your profile can be edited by running `notepad $PROFILE` and just dropping the snippet above into that file. If the file doesn't exist it will be created.

You can read more about the PSReadLine cmdlets on the [[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-5.1)] page, and more about the `[Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]` class [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.psconsolereadline?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0)

Comment: you can use [`DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds?view=net-5.0) directly without a TImeSpan

Comment: Yes, so something like this: `$unixDate = [System.DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()` I did notice when comparing this with the `New-TimeSpan` that the `[System.DateTimeOffset]` is in UTC, and `New-TimeSpan` was in local.

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](http://www.filedropper.com/unixtimestamp), click download (please do **not** use wget.exe if you have it), then follow these steps: Right click on downloaded file > Properties > Shortcut then you will find something that says None (exact), click that, then press Ctrl + Alt + [whatever key] or just press [whatever key] (you are required to use Ctrl + Alt and change [whatever key] to any character and remove the brackets). Restart the computer, it should open [this](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) link in your default browser that was set in settings (to open settings app press Win key + I). Sorry, I do not know or can research about putting it in the cursor so here is what I know...